# python multidimensional array create with explicit size

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

The value of Index 1 changes in all rows in method1. How should I create an ar1 array correctly?

**method1:**

```
ar1= [[0] * 3] * 3

ar1[0][1]=5
print(ar1)
```

**method2:**

```
ar2=[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],

]
ar2[0][1]=5
print(ar2)
```

**output1:**

```
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0]]
```

**output2:**

```
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

(or)

```
arr1 = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

(or)

```
arr1 = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: This is actually a dup... but I haven’t seen all three places susccinctly in one place... the linked article is worth a read... it will explain why your first arr1 attempt was a problem.